# Sharepoint Online - Powershell to retrieve URL and any full control users assigned to that URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have created a power-shell script to list all the subsites and users who have full control to that individual subsite however it's coming up with an error - The collection has not been in itialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. Can someone please have a look at my script? I need it to look like this:

URL                 Users
dsff.com            joe bloggs, ava who, nerida may
gfhsdk.com          tim ha, mary boo

My code is attached!
Thanks,
Clare

```
'$webs = Get-pnpsubwebs -recurse 
foreach ($web in $webs) {
    $users = $web.siteusers
    write-host "Processing " $web.url -foregroundcolor cyan

    Write-host "Site Owners" -foregroundcolor green
    foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($web.DoesUserHavePermissions($user,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::FullMask)) {
        write-host $user.Name
    }
    write-host $web.Url
 }
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the script given in [this](https://anandthearchitect.com/2017/03/14/sharepoint-online-get-site-owners-list-from-all-sites/) blog post helps you. Adding the same script here in case the blog hyperlink is not accessible.

```
param (  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
         [string]$TenantName )

#Form a SharePoint Admin URl
$AdminURL = "https://$tenantName" + "-admin.sharepoint.com"

#Add SharePoint PowerShell Snap-in and Importing the SharePoint Online module
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Import-Module ‘C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell’ -DisableNameChecking

#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminURL -Credential (Get-Credential)

#Headers for the data
"Site URL`tOwner`tUsers`tGroup`tGroup Members" | Out-File -FilePath .\SharePointSiteOwners.csv 

#Get all Sites (Root sites only)
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All

#Process all sites
foreach($site in $sites)
{
    $siteURL = $site.Url 
    $siteOwner = $site.Owner

    Write-Host $siteURL -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host $siteOwner -ForegroundColor Cyan


    #Get all users with Site Owner permissions
    $siteAdmins = Get-SPOUser -Site $siteURL -Limit All | select LoginName,IsSiteAdmin | ? { $_.ISSiteAdmin } 

    #Collect all site owners (user accounts) to a variable $siteUsers
    $siteUsers = ""
    foreach($siteAdmin in $siteAdmins) { $siteUsers += $siteAdmin.LoginName + " , " }


    Write-Host $siteUsers -ForegroundColor Cyan

    #Get all Groups from the site permissions
    $sitegroups = Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $siteURL

    #Get Group info and members that have site owners permissions
    foreach ($sitegroup in $sitegroups)
    {
        $i = 0
        foreach($role in $sitegroup.Roles)
        {
            if ( $role.Contains("Site Owner") -or $role.Contains("Full Control") )
            {
                $i = $i + 1
                Write-Host $sitegroup.Title -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
                Write-Host $sitegroup.Users -ForegroundColor "Blue"

                if ($i -gt 1)
                {
                    "`t`t`t" + $sitegroup.Title + "`t" + $sitegroup.Users | Out-File -FilePath .\SharePointSiteOwners.csv -Append
                }
                else
                {
                    "$siteURL`t$siteOwner`t$siteUsers`t" + $sitegroup.Title + "`t" + $sitegroup.Users | Out-File -FilePath .\SharePointSiteOwners.csv -Append
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```